# Which component to use in JSF or PrimeFaces for an incrementally updated text area?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have been looking around for a component in JSF or PrimeFaces which could be incrementally updated with new message for a broadcasted messages output panel.

I can think of only taking all of the messages and flushing them on a `p:inputTextArea` (with `readonly` set) every time a new message comes, but this sounds grossly inefficient.

Can a `p:dataTable` be used here? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I think, that [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chat.jsf) primefaces example for ajax push answers your question (you need custom JS function)...

Comment: is that a component i see raw html being pushed to the div by jQuery?

Comment: There is no component afaik, you have to do this infrastructure by yourself, because the JSF components are not very partial-update friendly in general...

Answer (score 0):

PF 3 already have some push support based on websockets, try at: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/chat.jsf